# How to divide sum in number from count in having?

Tags: sql

I have the following SQL query:

```
SELECT SUM(m1) as m1, 
SUM(m2) as m2, 
SUM(m3) as m3, 
SUM(m4) as m4 FROM `test` 
GROUP BY type HAVING count(*) > 300;
```

I need to divide each SUM on value `count(*)` in having condition. Like this:

```
SELECT SUM(m1) / count(*) as m1, 
SUM(m2)  / count(*) as m2, 
SUM(m3)  / count(*) as m3, 
SUM(m4)  / count(*) as m4 FROM `test` 
GROUP BY type HAVING count(*) > 300;
```

How to improve this query, avoiding `/ count(*)` in each operation `SUM()`?

Comment: I tried to use also subquery

Comment: that looks remarkably like you're calculating "arithmetic means"; there's a built in operator, called `avg`, just for that.  any reason you're not using it?

Comment: Sure, you are right I need just replace `SUM(m)` on `AVG(m1)` it works

Comment: Post this as answer I will apply

Comment: Replace every `SUM(m?)  / count(*)` with `AVG(m?)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The canonical solution is `avg()` -- and that is probably what you really intend:

```
SELECT AVG(m1) as m1, AVG(m2) as m2, AVG(m3) as m3, AVG(m4) as m4
FROM `test` 
GROUP BY type
HAVING count(*) > 300;
```

However, this is really equivalent to:

```
SELECT SUM(m1) / count(m1) as m1, 
       SUM(m2) / count(m2) as m2, 
       SUM(m3) / count(m3) as m3, 
       SUM(m4) / count(m4) as m4
FROM `test` 
GROUP BY type
HAVING count(*) > 300;
```

`COUNT(*)` is not the same as `COUNT(m1)` because of `NULL` values.  The formal equivalent would be:

```
SELECT AVG(COALESCE(m1, 0)) as m1,
       AVG(COALESCE(m2, 0)) as m2,
       AVG(COALESCE(m3, 0)) as m3,
       AVG(COALESCE(m4, 0)) as m4
FROM `test` 
GROUP BY type
HAVING count(*) > 300;
```

As I say, though, you probably *intend* the simple `AVG()`, but this is the correct equivalent.

Answer (score 2):

looks like you just want to calculate averages, e.g:

```
SELECT
  AVG(m1) as m1, AVG(m2) as m2 -- …
FROM test
GROUP BY type
HAVING count(*) > 300;
```

would do what you want, there are lots more aggregate functions here:

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/functions-aggregate.html

Answer (score 1):

Cant you just use the AVG() function?

if not, perform a count first and use the result in the next query, but AVG() is better, or are you trying to do something else entirely?